# Implementing MVC in Iphone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

Hi I am new to iPhone Progrmamming. Can anybody please tell me from where to learn implemetation of MVC in iPhone.

Thanks 
Gurpreet

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Core Data template in Xcode, if you're looking for an example of MVC.

Comment: Thanks Alex. i want ot get into 2d gaming for iPhone. Can you please suugest me some good 2d gaming engine, because I am beginner and i have no idea about that